# Java : if condition : using a variable inside the if as a condition of the if

Tags: java, if-statement, variables

As a beginner, I'm trying to code something like that. For sure, the wrong way, because it doesn't work at all.
What I'm trying to do is :
use the results i can get when I do something inside a if loop and use these results to calculate conditions the next time I enter the if...
To be more understanable, I want to do the same thing if cond1 && cond2 are TRUE but not to early even if the situation occurs (delay of 1000) and not at a value under the previous one...

I don't know how to code this, for the first time I enter the if and for the others...
Can you help me please???
Thanks a lot.

```
boolean cond_1 = a < 10;
boolean cond_2 = b < 15;
boolean cond_delay = (time_now - time_i_have_done_something) > 1000;
boolean cond_value = value_now > value_i_have_done_something;

if (cond_A1 == true && cond_A2 == true && cond_delay == true) {
 do something;
 long time_i_have_done_something = do_something.gettime();
 double value_i_have_done_something = do_something.getvalue();
}
```

Example of the logic I want to implement :

```
if (cond_A1 == true) { // firt occurence at 7 h 30 min 00 sec 000 ms
time = gettime();
value = getvalue();
IOrder order = engine.submitOrder("EURUSD", instrument, orderCommand, 1); 
}
if (cond_A1 == true) { // second occurence at 7 h 30 min 00 sec 190 ms
// do nothing because time between occurence#1 and occurence#2 < 1000 ms  
}
if (cond_A1 == true) { // firt occurence at 7 h 30 min 01 sec 050 ms
// execute this because time between occurence#1 and occurence#3 > 1000 ms 
time = gettime();
value = getvalue();
IOrder order = engine.submitOrder("EURUSD", instrument, orderCommand, 1); 
}
```

Comment: I did not understand your question, but you don't have to put == true, you can just put the variable in the if, It's like checking if true == true.

Comment: do while loop can be helpful

Comment: Pls explain your question clearly, unable to understand

Comment: The if statement must be entered only if a after a delay. But the time of the event is known in the if statement itself.

Comment: then how are you calculating the value before `(time_now - time_i_have_done_something) > 1000`

Comment: I want the code keep testing the cond_A1 and cond_V1 (and keep track of it (time and value it has occured)), but executes what is is the if-statement or in the else-statement not before a delay.
Example : 
cond_A1 is true -> execute if
    gettime() when it happened 
    getvalue() when it happened

cond_A1 happens again 28ms after (delay was 1000 so do nothing)

cond_A1 happens again 1789ms after (1789>1000 so execute that is in the if statement)

And so on...

Comment: if cond_A1 is true and cond_V1 is true just after, no delay, just go to else

Comment: See my new edit for an example. Sorry, I'm french so I have to manage not only the informatique language :)

Comment: I want it to work more than twice. For the if and for the else the same way.  I don't understand the end of your message. I would like more than a idea. Or something very detailled and commented.

Comment: Yes you only need it

Comment: OK the clean up has been done.

Comment: @PAL2BLG Please see the comment on my answer.

Comment: Since you have cleaned your Question, do you think perhaps it would help other readers if you also cleaned your comments here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will loop, and before the action `doSomething()` is called, if will check that a condition is true, and that 1 second has passed since the action was last taken. It will also wait for the first action to be taken at a 1 second delay because the first call is not treated as a special case. This can be fixed by declaring start like this:

```java
long start = System.nanoTime() - timeBetween;
```

I put in a repeat variable with the value of 5. That can of course be removed.

I chose to not `sleep()` the thread, but just `yield()` for the processor to be able to take on other tasks while also being able to just busy-loop the program:

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class StackOverflowTest {

  public static void main(String [] args){
    StackOverflowTest test = new StackOverflowTest();
    test.notTooFast();
  }

  public void notTooFast(){
    boolean condition1  = true;
    long    timeBetween = 1_000_000_000;  // 1 second.
    long    start       = System.nanoTime();
    int     repeat      = 5;              // run the loop only 5 times. 

    while (repeat > 0) {  // or for an endless loop, use: while (true)

      // has timeBetween passed since last time?
      if (condition1 && (System.nanoTime() - start > timeBetween)) {

        start = System.nanoTime(); // reset the time
        doSomething(repeat--);     // don't forget to decrease the counter.

      } else {
        Thread.currentThread().yield();  // hint to yield this threads current use of a processor.
      }
    }
  }

  // just print something for the sake of the example:
  public void doSomething(int countdown){
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime
                         .now()
                         .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)
                       + ": Doing something "
                       + countdown);
  }
}
```

It prints:

```java
2020-07-15T13:30:34.409: Doing something 5
2020-07-15T13:30:35.350: Doing something 4
2020-07-15T13:30:36.350: Doing something 3
2020-07-15T13:30:37.349: Doing something 2
2020-07-15T13:30:38.350: Doing something 1
```

I imagine, the line

```java
doSomething(repeat--);
```

should probably be replaced with something like this:

```java
repeat--;
IOrder order = engine.submitOrder("EURUSD", instrument, orderCommand, 1);
```

---

Instead of `Thread.currentThread().yield();`, you can also use

```java
try {        
  Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); // 1 second.
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
  // handle whichever way
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  // reset interrupt flag
}
```

which will effective put the thread to sleep for 1 second.

Comment: @PAL2BLG I've seen your edit. I'm not sure it improved my answer.

Comment: The time between time between #5 and #4 looks like it's less than 1 second because the start variable is set at the very beginning. You can print the start variable instead (`System.out.println(start);`) to see that it's not *actually* running it less than 1 second apart. Of course if you use the `sleep(1000)` instead, it will take *at least* a second between calls.

Comment: I cannot know how long it takes to complete your `engine.submitOrder(getLabel(instrument), instrument, orderCommand, 0.1);` code, so I cannot know what you mean by "it is always true, whatever the timebetween I choose". have you tried to use 10 seconds? Or perhaps set the start value after the call instead of before the call? Also, have you tried to just run the code I have posted here, to play around with it before using the bits in your own code?

Comment: Please note that your `cond_A1` is a `boolean`, so you do not need to test if it's true by `if (cond_A1 == true  &&...`. You can simply use `if (cond_A1  &&...`

Comment: I think you need to time how long it takes to make your call by printing the time before and after. If it takes less than one second, you will need to use a different approach if you want a pause of a second between calls, like making the thread sleep or setting start after the call, as I suggested in a previous comment.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you do not seem to be using a loop in your code. So to be it doesn't look like you are calling this more than once. And since you have set `long start = System.nanoTime() - time_between;` there will be no delay when you call `onFeedData` since that method sets the start variable every time you call it.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It's always false. Sorry.
I've tried 10s and switching the start value and the call. Same result.
I'm backtesting the program on historical data that are available from a feedData function. So, is the system.nanotime() the right way to gettime is these conditions ?
The function feeddata.gettime() returns me the time where the program is in the historical data i'm backtesting with... (If it can help)

Comment: Yes, `System.nanotime()` is, in my opinion, the best way to test how long it takes. If you understand how this code works, then my best advice for you is to check the content of your variables while debugging. It's the more reliable way to understand what is going on with your system.

Comment: I'm using a loop because the onfeeddata() function executes everytime we received a new data from the feed.I've set it to 5 minutes for my backtesting scenario.
Only with the Cond_A1 in the if and the Cond_V1 in the esle, the program runs well, excecuting the engine.submitOrder more than 300 times in one month of backtesting.

Comment: If you want to have a look : https://www.dukascopy.com/wiki/en/development/strategy-api/instruments/feeds

Comment: If you are using a loop to call `onfeeddata()` then you should set the start value from that loop, not inside the `onfeeddata()` method. Think of my `doSomething()` as your `onfeeddata()`. You do not even have to use it in your if statement, if you just want to to space out your calls.

Comment: The onfeeddata() is the loop itself

Comment: I looked at the code in your proposed edit, and I did not see a loop inside `onFeedData()`. I Only saw an `if` statement. But that doesn't change that you're setting `start` in there so that there is no delay. It cannot time between calls also because you are initializing and setting `start` inside the method being called.